# Are frequencies on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Can we talk about different frequencies of sounds, and pitches, on here? Obviously, different animals can hear different frequencies and pitches so this would be a nice area to explore.

e.g. Can we ask about the different frequencies that an animal makes, and which animals could hear these?

Comment: Can you explain or give an example? Thanks!!

Comment: @Shannon added!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds on-topic for me-- with the caveat that (1) much of this information is readily accessible online BUT (2) there is a LOT more information than what is readily published (I'm guilty here)!  So, I think the key is to encourage people to first do their homework and then ask the question. A reminder on asking good questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Also sounds very on-topic for me. Bioacoustics has a lot to do with the sounds animals make, and also as a result, what sounds they can hear.

It makes sense to talk about both parts of the topic from the basic and conservation science perspectives.